# RTE and OS in Autosar

Tags: operating-system, rte, autosar

Can anybody clarify me about the integration of RTE and OS , I mean:
I got this statement from a paper about RTE "During the process of ECU configuration, a
mapping between operating system tasks and existing runnables is created that
is later used by the RTE to define and perform scheduling and execution of the
runnables according to their specification"

My question is how does the RTE make possible the execution of a runnable, since they are comprised in a task does that mean that RTE changes the state of that task from "Ready" to "Executing", and how its that translated in hardware .
By translated in hardware I mean when RTE transmits a data between atomic software components in the same ECU , in Hardware it's just a shared memory between the components.

So could anyone give me an insight about the cooperation of RTE and OS ,

For example when a data comes at a port of the ASWC so the event of reception is triggered , how does the RTE trigger to run a runnable does it change the PC  to the PC of that address of the instruction of the task that contains the runnable?So does the RTE plays the role of the scheduler?